# AutoMapper Return an empty list when Mapping two lists

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to convert one List to another using AutoMapper, but it returns an empty list

This is my source object

```
public class Charge
{
    public int ChargeID { get; set; }
    public string ChargeName { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

This is my destination object

```
public class ChargeVM
{
    public int ChargeID { get; set; }
    public string ChargeName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

This is my AutoMapper mapping

```
 List<Charge> chargeList= GetActiveChargeTemplates();   

 Mapper.CreateMap<List<Charge>, List<ChargeVM>>();

 List<ChargeVM>  list=Mapper.Map<List<Charge>, List<ChargeVM>>(chargeList);
```

this return list as an empty list with count=0.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 8):

Change

```
Mapper.CreateMap<List<Charge>, List<ChargeVM>>();
```

to

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Charge, ChargeVM>();
```

You don't have to explicitly create maps for list, only the objects in the list.

Comment: Thank you very much HansVG . You saved my day